# regex search line not contain string preceding another

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex to find lines of a file containing a string that is not preceded by another.

Specifically, I need to search for lines that contain the "fixed" string but they do not come preceded by "#" in any previous position. Examples:

```
fixed xxx
# fixed yyy
aaa # fixed zzz
fixed www # bbb
```

Regexp should return only this lines:

```
fixed xxx
fixed www # bbb
```

Can this be done with a single regex? How?

I'm using PHP.

Thank you all.

PD: Sorry for my English.

Comment: Regex Negative Lookbehind

Comment: If `fixed` should always be at the start of the line, you can use regular string functions (based on the examples).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the regex you need (without using any lookarounds):

```
/^[^#\n]*fixed[^\n]*$/m
```

Explanation:

```
^ - beginning of a line
[^#\n]* - any amount of chars that are not "#" and are not line breaks
fixed - the string itself
[^\n]* - any other characters that are not line breaks
$ - until the end of a line
/m - multiline modifier: http://php.net/manual/ro/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
```

In PHP:

```
$lines = "fixed xxx\n# fixed yyy\naaa # fixed zzz\nfixed www # bbb";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/^[^#]*fixed.*$/m', $lines, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "fixed xxx"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "fixed www # bbb"
  }
}
```

thx to @sln for the suggestions.

Comment: Might want to make `[^#]` -> `[^#\n]` so it don't span lines.

Comment: This is the job of /m modifier

Comment: Not really. /m only handles ^$. The regex matches `" here is\nfixed  \#"`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ro/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php :
When this modifier is set, the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately following or immediately before any newline in the subject string, respectively, as well as at the very start and end

Comment: That resolves to nothing to do with span lines. Your regex matches `"\n\n\n\nhere\n\n\nis\n\n\nan\n\n\nentire\n\n\nparagraph\n\n\n\nfixed \#"` Try it. `[^#]` matches newlines, cr's, any linebreak as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the comparisons are all by line, I would try something like this...

(in pseudo code)

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]"); //a string that starts with a number
string thisLine = input.getLine();

while(hasInput)
{
   string lastLine = thisLine;
   string thisLine = input.getLine();
   if(regex.hasMatch(lastLine)) 
   {
       System.out.println(thisLine)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the negative lookbehind way:

```
(?<!#\s)fixed.*
```

Example:

http://regex101.com/r/rR4eG1

PHP:

```
$string = "fixed xxx
# fixed yyy
aaa # fixed zzz
fixed www # bbb";

preg_match_all("/(?<!#\s)fixed.*/", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => fixed xxx
            [1] => fixed www # bbb
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex Negative Lookbehind: [Live Demo](https://eval.in/90560)

```
$reg = '/(?<!\#\s)(fixed.+)/';

$input = '
fixed xxx
# fixed yyy
aaa # fixed zzz
fixed www # bbb';

preg_match_all($reg, $input, $output);
$output = $output[0];

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fixed xxx
    [1] => fixed www # bbb
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach checks from the end of line back to beginning.
Incase of  `fixed  # fixed`

```
 #  '/^(?!.*\#.*fixed).*fixed.*/m'

 ^ 
 (?! .* \# .* fixed )
 .* 
 fixed
 .*
```